# In Android, where should database queries be kept?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, android-cursor

I have a small Android project, and I currently declare and call database (SQLite) queries in my Activity classes. However, the queries are somewhat verbose, and I find myself declaring and calling the same queries over and over after certain actions are performed by the user (such as changing the date and loading the data from that date). Thus, I am wondering if queries are supposed to be kept in a separate class (such as the Database Contract class?) or possibly even in their own methods that return a Cursor. I would imagine something along the lines of a method `getTransactionsByDate(Date newDate)` could be used. Is there an established pattern that I may not be aware of?

Comment: Keep them in another package other than the UI one. Also are you writing the raw queries, if yes, replace them with the Cursor or use any ORM library. for reference look on it https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```
public class DatabaseSource {

    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
    private DatabaseHelper mHelper;
    private Context mContext;

    public DatabaseSource(Context context){
        mContext = context;
        mHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException{
        mDatabase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close(){
        mDatabase.close();
    }

    public void insertData(int something){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
        values.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN, something);
        mDatabase.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null, values);

    }

    public Cursor getAll(){
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE");
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

This shortens the query calling procedure. In this example `DatabaseHelper` is a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` and has `onCreate` and `onUpdate` methods for the database.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what I was thinking.

Comment: @n0k no problem :)